# How do I get linux quotas to work?

Tags: linux, fstab, quota

I am trying to create a cap of 8gb per user on the /home dir.

here is my fstab line.

`UUID=ebec6b82-1e9a-4b9a-9f36-eb3586f2f6a7       /home  ext4    defaults,nofail,usrquota,grpquota        0 0`

The /home/aquota.user file does exist.

my test user is an unprivileged user called `capped`.

Here is the command that I am using to manually add the cap for now.

`sudo  setquota -u -F vfsv0 capped 7000000 8000000 1000000 1000000 /home`

I am then testing by creating a 12 gb file via `fallocate -l 12G 12gbtest-file`.

I am able to. I expect to get a warning or be blocked from taking this much space.

When I run `repquota -a |grep capped` it returns.

`capped    +- 9437552 7000000 8000000  6days      85 1000000 1000000`

What am I missing here? how to I get the hard limit to work?

Comment: As far as I can remember, aquota.user is created by the following command: `quotacheck -avug` which gathers information about the disk usage. Have you run it before assign you user's quota?